# try to move a file by nodeJS need administrator permission

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to move folders with files but that happend to me all files moved except  one , I used "wrench" ,"ncp" even "fs-extra" but still that file not allowed to move , I try move manual by windows give me that message ,
[image]

what can i do to move that file or what are like it by nodejs,

that last code i have used ncp

```
ncp(path.join(req.body.uploadPath,'package',resourceDirectoryName),path.join(req.body.uploadPath,'package'), function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err,'1');
          }
          console.log('done1')
         });
```

this error show up in console of nodejs

```
[ { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Nodejs\node\public\uploads\games\5ac775cabe577c55642f0282\package\flappy\html5game\tph_GoogleMobileAds.ext'
    errno: -4048,
    code: 'EPERM',
    syscall: 'lstat',
    path: 'D:\\Nodejs\\node\\public\\uploads\\games\\5ac775cabe577c55642f0282\\package\\flappy\\html5game\\tph_GoogleMobileAds.ext' } ]
```

Comment: Have you tried running Node itself as an administrator/running Node from an admin command prompt?

Comment: @JoeClay no i don't try this i always run it from Visual Studio Code prompt

Comment: i have try by admin command and still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

You could give read/write permission to that folder using chmod -R 777 through terminal. E.g: chmod -R 777 D:\Nodejs\node\public\uploads\games\5ac775cabe577c55642f0282\package\flappy

It gives read/write permission to that folder and its subfolder/files. Then you can move and copy and modify them freely.